# ob_flush() not working?

Tags: php, api, shopify, flush

I read the other questions that seem to have the same issue but none of the responses are working for me, so I'll try again.

I'm using Shopify's API. I need to update every product's Image properties. I have more than 1600 products. I need to make 7 API calls for every product. Being that Shopify only allows 1 API call per half-second, I have sleeps added in. The issue is that I'm hitting a timeout obviously, by slowing the PHP down to 800 seconds.

I tried to add ob_flush to try and not have the timeout, but it's not working and not outputting anything. I'm using Safari if that helps. Here's my code:

```
<?php
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

$count = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://xxxx:xxxx@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products/count.json"));
sleep(500000);
$count = $count -> count;
$modulo = $count % 50;
$loop = ($count-$modulo)/50;
$a=0;
for ($x = 1; $x < $loop; $x++){
$products1 = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://xxxx:xxxx@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?page=$x"));
usleep(500000);
for ($y = 0; $y < 50; $y++) {
    echo $a++;
    echo ") ";
    echo $products1 -> products[$y] -> id;
    $title = $products1 -> products[$y] -> title;
    $id = $products1 -> products[$y] -> id;
    if (strpos($title, 'xxxx') !== false) {
        echo ": skipped (doesn't have extra pics)";
        continue;
    }else{
        $images = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://xxxx:xxxx@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products/".$ID."/images.json"));
        $onlyImage = $images -> images[0] -> id;
        $url = "https://xxxx:xxxx@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products/".$id.".json";
        $product = array(
            "product" => array(
            "id" => $ID,
            "images" => array(array($onlyImage)),
            ),
        );
        $data_json = json_encode($product);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
        $response  = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (strpos($response, '200') !== false) {
            echo ': Images Deleted ('.$title.')';
        }else{
            echo ': Failed to Delete Images ('.$title.')';
        }
        sleep(1);
        $variants = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://xxxx:xxxx@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products/".$id."/variants.json"));
        $count = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://xxxx:xxxx@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products/".$id."/variants/count.json"));
        $variants_count = $count -> count;
        $variants_list = array();
        for ($z = 0; $z < $variants_count; $z++) {
            $variants_list[] = $variants -> variants[$y] -> id;
        }
        $url = "https://xxxx:xxxx@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products/".$id."/images/".$onlyImage.".json";
        $image = array(
            "image" => array(
            "id" => $onlyImage,
            "variant_ids" => $variants_list,
            ),
        );
        $data_json = json_encode($image);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
        $response  = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (strpos($response, '200') !== false) {
            echo ', Variant Images Updates ('.$title.')';
        }else{
            echo ', Failed to Update Variant Images ('.$title.')';
        }
        usleep(1500000);
    }
    echo "<br>";    
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: so just increase the the script timeout?

Comment: Im not even sure if thats the issue, Im getting a 500 error response. how do I do that?

Comment: set_time_limit(0);

Comment: also the input to `sleep()` is seconds. 500000 seconds is almost six days

Comment: @Gordon ha! Thats supposed to be usleep. Probably my issue... ill try that

Comment: and I'd probably make the usleep decision dependent on the X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit http header returned when using the api. There is no need to sleep when that isnt approaching the limit. see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: @Gordon Can you help me out with that? I don't know how to get that response. Also, even with switching to usleep(), it is still not flushing...

Comment: tbh, I dont get why you think output buffering would help here. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Gordon also, the Shopify API reference writes that the call limit is 40 per 20 seconds

Comment: @Gordon either way, I want to know where my code is up to instead of waiting 20 minutes to see if anything worked

Comment: Well, if you need to make 7 API calls per product and the limit recovers by 2 per second, you can make 7 calls, then sleep for 4 seconds and go again. You shouldn't need any output buffering for this, nor do you need to sleep for 8 minutes. Like I said, I don't understand why you think OB is the solution here. OB doesnt affect script timeouts. If you want to increase the timeout, just set the timeout with set_time_limit as mentioned above.

Comment: still not working with set_time_limit(0). Am i supposed to be doing this for every loop or only once at the beginning? Does it override the default timeout limit?